# Neo4j a way to keep pipe results and regenerate variable

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I have a User node with two properties: partitaionA and partitionB which I generated from unionFind in graph algorithms package.

I want to do something like below but keep expanding like union operation.
partitionA -> partitionB -> partitionA -> partitionB -> ......... until the number of users in the group does not grow.

```
Match (u: User) 
WHERE u.partitionA = 123 
WITH collect(u.partitaionB) as next_level 
MATH (uu: User) 
WHERE uu.partitionB in next_level 
RETURN uu
```

Is there any stored procedure can do something like this?
Not sure what is the best way to describe this question.

For the data model, I only have User node in this case and User node have 2 properties: partitionA and partitionB.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you want the final result to look like. Can you clarify what the data model is here?

Comment: Just added in the post.